# Is there a better name for "Poison Agile"?

Tags: agile, development-methodologies, waterfall

We have been continually facing this challenge during the last year. Upper IT management wants us to use Agile Methodology internally (development team) while the external client refuses to do so and wants hard commitments with clearly defined requirements, clearly defined deadlines, and clearly defined payments and fines.

To our understanding this is not Agile but Waterfall.

Since the IT management wants us to pretend Agile by doing daily stand up meetings, doing epics, and internal iterations we decided to informally *christen* the methodology as "Poison Agile". We believe it's risky to work this way and it could lead to a lot of problems related to the disconnect between the internal plan and the external hard commitments.

Now, we like *Poison Agile* since the name directly conveys it's something risky.

On the flip side, it sounds a bit sarcastic and ironic and we would prefer a more impartial term.

Is there a more accepted, official term for this methodology/conundrum?

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question, please elaborate. This is a real concern for us, and we think clear communication is key to resolve the current problem.

Comment: The thing that makes Agile work is easy and fast communication with the stakeholders.  If 10 programmers are waiting on one busy "domain expert" for elaboration of the individual features, Agile has problems.  If 10 programmers have 10 (or more) domain experts on call, it works.

Comment: @user949300 Thank you, I totally agree. Now, is there a name for this "disaster" we are in?

Comment: Some people call it "Faux Agile". You said "the external client refuses to do so and wants hard commitments with clearly defined requirements" - this is a problem with the business contract between the two parties. You devs can't solve this, the (business) decision makers can solve this. It's the cost/scope/time triangle - your decision makers *cannot* allow the client to set in stone all 3 of these, they can only pick two and decide on a strategy to manage the risk of the third one being an unknown, or refuse the job. Agile is a way to manage that risk, and it should be sold to them as such.

Comment: P.S. "the external client [...] wants [...] clearly defined requirements" - if they want that to be *produced by you*, that's work in itself, you should charge them hefty for that alone, even if you don't write a line of code afterwards (e.g. if they choose not to continue with the project, or they take your requirement spec and give it to someone else to execute)

Comment: We cannot charge extra. It's already agreed per contract. and we need to provide the final product in 18 months.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about the future; your bosses should write better contracts. The company shouldn't allow itself to get in a position where it's basically guaranteed to drop the ball or fail, unless the heroic efforts of its devs miraculously save the day after some big time crunch and caffeine-fueled overtime. Contrary to popular belief, you are not supposed to work yourself to death

Comment: If you can clearly see that the project is going to fail and are unable to communicate that fact effectively there is a name for this: [Death March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(project_management)).

Comment: Ron Jeffries, one of the OG agile practitioners, has blogged a lot about the [problems of “Dark Scrum”](https://ronjeffries.com/categories/dark-scrum/) and “Dark Agile”. However, it is unhelpful to think about fixed scope + time as anti-agile. While some of the agile values like “responding to change” don't apply as clearly, others do. (And there will definitely be a change in plans when the schedule almost inevitably slips…). On the level of your team, you can still use many agile-associated practices that make software development enjoyable and productive, such as Spikes or Retrospectives.

Comment: Agile was never intended to give you a blank check to develop forever. Agile gives you a way to create good enough software over and over and get feedback  early even as a deadline looms. Even if the customer refuses to look at demos you can use them to show management clearly how short your are of your target requirements early. Sure, Agiles ability to react to change is being ignored. But that still lets you react if it turns out someone changes their mind about what a carved in stone requirement really means.

Comment: Doing scrum mindlessly is called "zombie scrum". And your client wanting one package deal with specs upfront allows you to apply whatever way of working internally because there should be no interaction with your client. Whatever you make won't have to be useful or even usable, it should just meet the specs. Think of it as one very long iteration. You may get a follow-up project to make it useful/usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really an issue here. You are working in an agile way, the client will still get updates each sprint on your progression towards their goals. Don't make a big deal out of it.

If the client can specify all their requirements up front, then great. plop em in the backlog and estimate off you velocity on the last project or a finger lick + safety margin.

If they can't, then great. Write down what they say and charge em extra when they want to change it/clarify.

The danger is showing them unfinished work when they don't want to see it. Don't frame it as an iteration towards a goal. Don't have a meeting, just send progress reports. Demo features only when you are 100% sure they match the requirements you were given and ask if the client would like that demo.

Comment: In our case, the client does not get any update on sprints. They don't really know about the internal agile methodology. We can't charge them extra either. It's already set in stone. We have 18 months (as per contract) and we cannot negotiate it.

Comment: danger avoided then. just use the demo as an internal check to see if you are on target for the 18 months

Comment: OMG. I'm gonna quit. Seriously... I can't compress 36 months of work in 18 months, "because Agile is more productive".

Comment: why? like 80% of agile projects are like this. Even if the client says they like agile and are paying per sprint, they mean they are paying for dev time and they still have concrete goals and a budget

Comment: presumably you get paid a daily rate whether the project meets its deadline or not.

Comment: I guess what you mean is your estimates on the backlog are being ignored. Don't stress it, they are just guesses and you'd be having the same problem in waterfall anyway

Comment: Thank you Ewan. I'm going to try not to stress out, but I already see the blame game going on.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra, it is the problem of whoever signed that contract (and the management layers above them) that all the financial risk is carried by your company. Do not let them make it your problem, especially if you have made it clear early and often that the timeline is unrealistic.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thank you. Yeah, I think my guts tell me this is going to be a disaster. I'll take it easy.